# Lost write permission in Samba 4.5

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, samba

I updated a machine from Debian Jessie to Stretch, which also upgraded the Samba version from 4.2.14 to 4.5.16.
I can mount a Samba share, browse and read it, but permission is denied when I try to write something.

My smb.conf looks like this and worked fine on Samba 4.2.14:

```
[global]
   workgroup = video
   server string = %h server (Samba %v)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   invalid users = root
   security = user  
   map to guest = Bad User
   os level = 33
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY
   unix charset = UTF-8
   strict allocate = yes
   log level = 3

[backup]
   comment = backup
   path = /mnt/backup
   writeable = yes
   public = yes
   force user = vdr
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
```

I found the following in the Samba logs:

```
[2020/07/15 09:55:06.621634,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:178(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user []\[vdr]@[] with the new password interface
[2020/07/15 09:55:06.621717,  3] ../source3/auth/auth.c:181(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [VDR]\[vdr]@[]
[2020/07/15 09:55:06.621865,  3] ../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:400(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'vdr' in passdb.
[2020/07/15 09:55:06.621922,  2] ../source3/auth/auth.c:315(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [vdr] -> [vdr] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
[2020/07/15 09:55:06.622054,  3] ../source3/auth/auth_util.c:1611(do_map_to_guest_server_info)
  No such user vdr [] - using guest account
```

The user vdr exists in /etc/samba/smbpasswd.
Where else should I look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: **smbpasswd -a vdr** solved my problem. Seems like Samba 4.5 became more strict compared to Samba 4.2.